# Can we apply an Itō formula to find an expression for $f(t,X_t)$, if $f$ is taking values in a Hilbert space?

Tags: probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, numerical-methods, stochastic-analysis

Let

- $U$ and $H$ be separable Hilbert spaces
- $Q\in\mathfrak L(U)$ be nonnegative and symmetric with finite trace
- $U_0:=Q^{1/2}U$
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(W_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a $Q$-Wiener process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$
- $X_0$ be a $H$-valued random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$
- $v:[0,\infty)\times H\to H$ be continuously Fréchet differentiable with respect to the first argument and twice continuously Fréchet differentiable with respect to the second argument
- $\xi:\Omega\times[0,\infty)\times H\to\operatorname{HS}(U_0,H)$ suitable for the following

> Assuming that $$X_t=X_0+\int_0^tv_s(X_s)\;{\rm d}s+\int_0^t\xi_s(X_s)\;{\rm d}W_s\;\;\;\text{for }t>0\;,\tag 1$$ I would like to use an Itō-like formula to find an expression for $$Y_t:=v_t(X_t)\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge 0\;.\tag 2$$ However, the Itō formula (see [Da Prato, Theorem 4.32](https://books.google.de/books?id=H-VSAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=%22valued+predictable+process+Bochner+integrable%22&source=bl&ots=u8gTivSmkd&sig=86ZpVCJpDd3Snz5vCd5ri7yjMjo&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDyPzyoK_MAhWnKJoKHaGIDAwQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22valued%20predictable%20process%20Bochner%20integrable%22&f=true)) for $(1)$ can only be used to find an expression for $f_t(X_t)$, if $f$ is a continuously partially Fréchet differentiable mapping $[0,\infty)\times H\to\color{red}{\mathbb R}$.

Since I want to derive a SPDE for $Y$, I'm unsure what I need to do. Maybe we can do the following: Let $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an orthonormal basis of $H$ and $$v^{(n)}_t(x):=\langle v_t(x),e_n\rangle_H\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N\;.$$ Then, each $v^{(n)}$ is continuously partially Fréchet differentiable and we can apply the Itō formula to find an expression for $$Y^{(n)}_t:=v_t^{(n)}(X_t)\;\;\;\text{for }t\ge 0\;.$$ Is this a good idea? We should be able to obtain $(2)$ by $$Y=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}Y^{(n)}e_n\;.$$ Later, I'm interested in numerically obtaining $Y$.

---

**EDIT**: By the referenced version of the Itō formula, we obtain

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\langle v(t,X_t),e_n\rangle_H&=\langle v(0,X_0),e_n\rangle_H+\int_0^t\langle{\rm D}u(s,X_s)(\xi_s(X_s){\rm d}W_s),e_n\rangle_H\\
&+\int_0^t\langle\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(s,X_s),e_n\rangle_H+\langle{\rm D}u(s,X_s)(u_s(X_s)),e_n\rangle_H\\
&+\frac 12\operatorname{tr}\langle{\rm D}^2u(s,X_s)\left(\tilde\xi_s(X_s)\tilde\xi_s^\ast(X_s)\right),e_n\rangle_H{\rm d}s
\end{split}\tag 3
\end{equation}

where $\tilde\xi:=\xi Q^{1/2}$. I've got two questions:

1. Can we write the infinite system of equations $(3)$ as one equation, as it is possible in the case $H=\mathbb R^d$ and $e_n=n\text{-th standard basis vector}$? It seems like that's the case, cause almost all terms are simply projections to the $n$-th basis vector, but I don't know how I need to deal with the trace term.
2. In my real application, I have another known expression for $v(t,X_t)$. Thus, my SPDE would be obtained by equating the SPDE of the question with that other expression. Now the question is: I want to solve that SPDE numerically. Is there any recommended method for such a type of equation? [I should note that I will consider something like $H=[L^2(\mathcal V)]^3$ or $H=[H_0^1(\mathcal V)]^3$ for some bounded domain $\mathcal V\subseteq\mathbb R^3$].

Comment: Another book to check is Michel Metivier, *Semimartingales*.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for your comment, but the book you've mentioned is related to SDEs not S**P**DEs.

Comment: Well, I don't have a copy handy, but I have a note that it discusses stochastic calculus of Hilbert-space valued processes, so I thought it might have an appropriate version of Ito's formula.

Comment: You are correct, this can be written coordinatewise without any problems. 

It can also be written in $H$ exactly the same way it is written in $\mathbb{R}$ (except some obvious notation change). There is absolutely no problem with that if the equation coefficients are good.

There would be a problem only if there were some unbounded operators in the coefficients, in which case some [**mild Ito formula**](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3526) could have been used.

Comment: @zhoraster Thank you very much for your comment. Please take note of my edit. If $H=\mathbb R^d$, we're in the convenient case where we can choose $(e_1,\ldots,e_d)$ to be the standard basis of the euclidean space. In that case $\langle\text{something},e_n\rangle_H$ is considered to be the $n$-th component of $\text{something}$ and we can write all $d$ equations $(3)$ as one equation (where the derivatives are understood to be taken componentwise).

Comment: @zhoraster I've got some problems to understand how this generalizes to arbitrary $H$. In particular, I've got two questions and I've added them to the question. Maybe you know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This longer version of my comment addresses only the first question.

Yes, you can do that. Let, for simplicity, $v$ be independent of $t$, i.e. $v\colon H\to H$, and let it be twice continuously differentiable with bounded derivatives. Then $D^2 v(x)$ can be thought as a bilinear map $H\times H\mapsto H$. On the other hand, $\xi\xi^*(x)$ can be regarded as a trace class operator on $H$. In turn, the space of trace class operators is the closure of $H\otimes H$ with respect to the trace norm. Hence, the map $H\otimes H\mapsto H$ which sends $h\otimes g$ into $D^2v(x) (h,g)$ can be extended to the space of trace class operators by continuity; denote this by $\operatorname{tr}_H(D^2v(x)\cdot)$. This makes the writing $\operatorname{tr}_H\big(D^2v(X_s) \xi Q\xi^*(X_s)\big)$ meaningful as an element of $H$.

So you can write
$$
v(X_t) = v(X_0) + \int_0^t Dv(X_s)\Big(v(X_s)\mathrm{d}s + \xi_s(X_s) \mathrm{d}W_s\Big) \\
+ \frac12 \int_0^t \operatorname{tr}_H\big(D^2v(X_s) \xi Q\xi^*(X_s)\big)\mathrm{d}s.
$$

Long story short, it is just a matter of making some notation to write this in a coordinate-free form on $H$.

Comment: Did you intend to write "Let [...] $v$ be independent of $[0,\infty)$" (instead of $H$)?

Comment: @0xbadf00d, independent of $t$, sure.

Comment: You say, that "the space of trace class operators is the closure of $H\otimes H$ with respect to the trace norm". Do you have a reference for that statement?

Comment: @0xbadf00d, this seems pretty obvious to me. I will nevertheless give you a reference if I find this.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with operator theory. If $H\otimes H$ denotes the tensor product, how can its closure (why is the trace norm even applicable?) be a space of operators?

Comment: @0xbadf00d, yes, $H\otimes H$ can be identified with linear operators by $h_1\otimes h_2\mapsto A$ with $Ax = h_1 (h_2,x)$.

Comment: ${\rm D}^2u(t,x)$ can be considered as an element of $\mathfrak L(H)$. $\tilde\xi_t(x)$ is an element of $\mathfrak L(U,H)$ and hence $\tilde\xi_t(x)\tilde\xi_t^\ast(x)\in\mathfrak L(H)$. Thus, $$\langle\underbrace{{\rm D}^2u(s,X_s)\left(\tilde\xi_s(X_s)\tilde\xi_s^\ast(X_s)\right)}_{=:\;E\;\in \; \mathfrak L(H)},e_n\rangle_H\in H'\;.\tag 4$$ You seem to use an other interpretation of ${\rm D}^2u(t,x)$. In particular, you consider ${\rm D}^2u(t,x)$ as a bilinear mapping $H\times H\to H$, which is fine. The problem is that this mapping is evaluated at an operator in $(4)$.

Comment: That's fine too, cause the specific operator is trace class and you've shown how we can extend any $$H\otimes H\to H\;,\;\;\;\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\otimes y_i\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^nB(x_i,y_i)\;,$$ where $B$ is any bilinear mapping $H\times H\to H$, to the space of trace class operators. With your argumentation and that interpretation of ${\rm D}^2u(t,x)$ the expression $E$ makes sense now. But I still don't see how you've solved the actual "problem" of getting rid of the coordinate form $\langle E,e_n\rangle_H$.

Comment: Sorry, I am on a conference. Will respond when I back home, if I don't forget.

Comment: Still would be happy to hear from you.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I've edited the answer (there is nothing new, but missing $Q$ added). Concerning your question. It is still not very clear for me what do you need exactly. Essential is that the Ito term is defined canonically, independently of any base. And this is done the same way in any space: Hilbert, Banach, finite dimensional etc. Let me ask you a question: how would you write the Ito formula for a multidimensional $f$?